# Recording earliest login time for each day

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk, splunk-formula

I need to return the earliest login time per day for a single username. However, some returns do not match the login from that date. Query below:

```
index=app_redacted_int_* sourcetype="redacted" SessionState="Active" UserName=ABCDE123

| rex field=UserRealName "(?<IDNUM>\d+$)"

| bucket _time span=1d as day
| eval day=strftime(_time,"%F")

| stats earliest(SessionStateChangeTime) as SesssionStateChangeTime by day IDNUM UserRealName UserName
```

Results:

```
day             IDNUM               UserRealName             UserName              SessionStateChangeTime
2020-07-23       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/22/2020 09:48:52
2020-07-24       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/23/2020 12:47:13
2020-07-25       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/24/2020 07:23:01
2020-07-27       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/27/2020 07:54:34
2020-07-28       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/27/2020 07:54:34
2020-07-29       123                John Smith               ABCDE123              7/28/2020 07:32:04
```

As you can see, some days are returning their earliest login as a login from the previous day. I need the dates on the left side and the right side to be matching, and I need this all together in one query, I already know how to do it one query at a time. Thanks for taking your time to help! It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It would *appear* that on those dates you've binned, the earliest login time was from an earlier day

It *appears* you've conflated multiple dates in the data into expecting them to be "the same"

I would *strongly suspect* that `SesssionStateChangeTime` is not the field you want to look at - at least, not in the manner you're trying to now